# Print factorials backwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do a loop that gives factorials from 10 to 1.

So I have this code:

```
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,11):
    factorial = factorial * i
    print(i,'!=', factorial)
```

But this shows results like this:

```
1 != 1
2 != 2
3 != 6
```

However I want them this way:

```
10 != 3628800
9 != 362880
8 != 40320
```

I've tried few different things but nothing really works, any ideas please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
results = []
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,11):
    factorial = factorial * i
    results.append('{:2,}! = {:,}'.format(i, factorial))

print('\n'.join(reversed(results)))
```

Output:

```
10! = 3,628,800
 9! = 362,880
 8! = 40,320
 7! = 5,040
 6! = 720
 5! = 120
 4! = 24
 3! = 6
 2! = 2
 1! = 1
```

To reduce the amount of memory required, you could do it like this instead:

```
results = []
factorial = 1
for i in range(1, 11):
    factorial *= i
    results.append(factorial)

for i, value in enumerate(reversed(results)):
    print('{:2,}! = {:,}'.format(len(results)-i, value))
```

If you like list comprehensions, it could also be done in this somewhat hacky way:

```
res = []
res = [res[-1] for x in range(1, 11) if not res.append(x*res[-1] if res else 1)]

for i, value in enumerate(reversed(res)):
    print('{:2,}! = {:,}'.format(len(res)-i, value))
```

Comment: B.Mat: Be careful using this because it will consume large amounts of memory when computing larger factorials since it stores the entire list of them in memory.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compute `10!` you need to compute `9!` first, so your best approach in order to avoid redundant computation is to write a function/generator that computes the factorials `1!`, `2!`, ... and then reverse the results.

Like this, for example:

```
>>> def factorials(n):
...:    fact = 1
...:    for i in range(1, n+1):
...:        fact = fact*i
...:        yield fact
...:        
>>> n = 10
>>> facts = reversed(list(factorials(n)))
>>>
>>> for f, i in zip(facts, range(n, 0, -1)):
...:    print('{}! = {}'.format(i, f))
...:    
10! = 3628800
9! = 362880
8! = 40320
7! = 5040
6! = 720
5! = 120
4! = 24
3! = 6
2! = 2
1! = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Divide the task into *calculation* and *output*. Store the calculated values in a dictionary for later output. Storing the numbers in a dictionary is cheaper then storing all output strings to be reversed later - still, if you want to calculate very high factorials this will eventually overflow the memory you got.

By filling a dictionary incrementally you can reuse the last created factorial which reduces the complexety of computation.

That way you have all factorials at your bidding when printing them:

```
# calculation:
f = {}
for i in range(1,11):

    # the i-th factorial is equal to the (i-1)-th factorial multiplied by i
    # for f[1] you try to access f[0] which does not exists, hence we use the 
    # default value:   dict.get(key, defaultvalue_used_if_key_not_in_dict)
    f[i] = f.get((i-1),1) * i

# different ways of output:
sor = sorted(f,reverse=True)
# print top down
for key in sor:
    print(f"{key:>2}! == {f[key]}")

# top down, only even
for key in sor:
    if key % 2 == 0:
        print(f"{key:>2}! == {f[key]}")

# top down, only odd    
for key in sor:
    if key % 2 == 1:
        print(f"{key:>2}! == {f[key]}")

print(f)
```

Output:

```
10! == 3628800
 9! == 362880
 8! == 40320
 7! == 5040
 6! == 720
 5! == 120
 4! == 24
 3! == 6
 2! == 2
 1! == 1

10! == 3628800
 8! == 40320
 6! == 720
 4! == 24
 2! == 2

 9! == 362880
 7! == 5040
 5! == 120
 3! == 6
 1! == 1

# f 
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 6, 4: 24, 5: 120, 6: 720, 7: 5040, 8: 40320, 9: 362880, 10: 3628800}
```

See: [python.org Dict-Doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain you want to calculate factorial in that way, the only way the comes in mind is insert your output to a list\dictionary and print it after the calculations.

```
factorial = 1
factList = {}
for i in range(1,11):
    factorial = factorial * i
    factList[i] = factorial

for i in range(1,11):
    print(11-i, "!: ",factList[11-i])
```

Comment: But this shows exactly the same output I had before

Comment: Yes you're right, edited my answer (11-i) instead of i.

Comment: Works now. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
For factorial in python we could use `math.factorial()` [math — Mathematical functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

**Second:**
You want your list in `reversed` order.

So we just use a decreasing for loop `for i in range(x, 0, -1):`
`-1` is the step we are using, `x` is your starting point, `0` the end of the loop.

**Third:**
Using a generator to save memory.
In this case i am using `yield` [The Python yield keyword explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/)

**Finally:**
You can print out the generator using `for loop`

*Code Example:*

```
import math

def fact(x):
    for i in range(x, 0, -1):
        yield math.factorial(i)

results = fact(10)

for num in results:
    print(num)
```